# Expected number of bridges in a random subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, extremal-graph-theory

I am researching connectivity in random subgraphs and have come across the following problem.

A bridge between two vertices $a$ and $b$ of a graph $G$ is an edge $e$ such that removing $e$ from $G$ disconnects $a$ and $b$. Note that $e$ is not a bridge if $a$ and $b$ are not connected in $G$. Denote by $B_G(a, b)$ the number of bridges between $a$ and $b$.

For any graph $G$ on $n$ vertices (possibly with multiple edges) let $G(1/2)$ denote the random subgraph of $G$ obtained by sampling each edge independently with probability $1/2$. 
My question is then: Is there any non-trivial bound on $M=\mathbb E[B_{G(1/2)}(a, b)]$ in terms of $n$, which holds for all graphs $G$?

Trivially, $M\leq n-1$ as there can be at most $n-1$ bridges between $a$ and $b$ in any graph on $n$ vertices. However, I hope that either $M\leq n^{1/2}$ or perhaps even $M\leq n^{1/3}$. I have an example where $M=\Theta(\log n)$, which occurs if $a$ and $b$ are at each end of a path of length $n$ and each edge of the path is replaced by $\Theta(\log n)$ edges.

I have not been able to find any litterature addressing questions of this nature, so references would be much appreciated as well!

Comment: If your graph $G$ is some kind of giant random graph, then its random *sub*graph is also just some kind of giant random graph (of an other persuasion than $G$), and your question reduces to the particulars of the connection of $a$ and $b$ to its giant component, if any.

Comment: I am currently at grips with a similar question: a parametric family of subgraphs of the complete graph on $n$ vertices. Unfortunately $n$ is very far from $\gg 1$

Comment: That is very true. I am, however, looking for a solution for any given graph. What is your problem?

Comment: The problem is to *quickly* find a small *vertex* separator (not edge separator) for each subgraph, so that they all break down to small connected components. The obvious way would be to solve the problem just once, on the union of the subgraphs... except it exhibits a "giant" component (80% of the vertices, say), when the individual subgraphs do not.